# PIC MCC I2C setup help

Tags: i2c, digital-communications, debugging, mplabx, pic16f

I have made use of the MSSP1 in MPLABx's MCC (code configurator). I have set it up as an I2C slave device and initialized the setup in the code provided. I am making use of a MCP2221 as a master device that I am using to detect any I2C devices coupled. This works well when using my ESP32 as a slave device and is easily detected.  I am, however, not picking up my PIC16F18857 device when setting it up as a slave.  Below follows my PIC code and then the pythod script I run for I2C device detection.  Help regarding setting up the PIC as an I2C slave which can be detected would be greatly appreciated!

```
#include "mcc_generated_files/mcc.h"

/*
                         Main application
 */
void main(void)
{
    // initialize the device
    SYSTEM_Initialize();

    // When using interrupts, you need to set the Global and Peripheral Interrupt Enable bits
    // Use the following macros to:

    // Enable the Global Interrupts
    INTERRUPT_GlobalInterruptEnable();

    // Enable the Peripheral Interrupts
    //INTERRUPT_PeripheralInterruptEnable();

    // Disable the Global Interrupts
    INTERRUPT_GlobalInterruptDisable();

    // Disable the Peripheral Interrupts
    //INTERRUPT_PeripheralInterruptDisable();
    I2C1_Open();
    I2C1_Enable();
    
    while (1)
    {
        // Add your application code
        if(I2C1_IsRead()){
            I2C1_SendAck();
        }
    }
}
```

Python script:

```
from EasyMCP2221 import Device
from EasyMCP2221.I2C_Slave import I2C_Slave
import time

def main():
    # Initialize the EasyMCP2221 object
    mcp = Device()

    try:
        for i2c_address in range(256):
            try:
                # Initialize I2C Slave with the current address
                eeprom = I2C_Slave(mcp, i2c_address)
             
                # Send a dummy write request to check if the slave responds
                response = eeprom.write(b"\x00")  # Send a single byte
                eeprom_data = eeprom.read(1)      # Try reading 1 byte

                # Check if response received and the masked address matches
                if eeprom_data and (i2c_address & 0xFE == eeprom_data[0]):
                    print(f"I2C device found at address 0x{hex(i2c_address)[2:]}")
                    print(f"Device with address 0x{hex(i2c_address)[2:]} has been found.")
                    break  # Exit the loop if a device is found
                
            except:
                print(f"I2C device NOT found at address 0x{hex(i2c_address)[2:]}")

        print("Address scanning completed.")
        # time.sleep(2)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        pass


    #i2c_address = 0x50

    try:
        while True:
            # Send the message "Hello" to the I2C address
            message = b"H"  # Bytes object containing the message
            eeprom.write(message)  # Use the write method
            print("Message sent to MCP2221")

            # Wait for a short interval before sending the next message
            #time.sleep(5)

    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 1):

You have the interrupts disabled. Comment out this line:

```
 INTERRUPT_GlobalInterruptDisable();
```

and uncomment this line:

```
//INTERRUPT_PeripheralInterruptEnable();
```

Microchip used to have an example code that emulated an I2C EEPROM, but I can't find it on their website. Here's the essential parts:

The receive address function. This checks the address, and also resets any flags to indicate the beginning of a transaction.

```
    #define EEPROM_SELECT   0x30
    void i2c_receive_address(void)
    {
        i2c_address = (I2C2_Read() >> 1);
    
        if (i2c_address == EEPROM_SELECT)
        {
            eeprom_data_flag = false;
        }
        i2c_first_byte_flag = true;
    
    }
```

The receive data function:

```
void i2c_receive_data(void)
{
    uint_8 value;
    
    
    value = I2C2_Read();

    // Receive data for the simulated EEPROM.
    // The first byte we receive is the register address.
    // After that, bytes received get written to the simulated EEPROM.
    if (eeprom_data_flag == false)
    {
            eepromAddress = value;

            eeprom_data_flag = true;
    } else { 
            // the master has written data to store in the eeprom
            EEPROM_Buffer[eepromAddress++] = value;
    }
}
```

And the transmit data function:

```
void i2c_transmit_data(void)
{
    uint_8 value;
   
    // Read from the simulated EEPROM.
    value = EEPROM_Buffer[eepromAddress++];
    eeprom_data_flag = 1;

    I2C2_Write(value);
}
```

Finally, you need to register these functions with the interrupt service routine:

```
SYSTEM_Initialize();

I2C2_Enable();
I2C2_Open();

I2C2_SlaveSetWriteIntHandler(i2c_transmit_data);
I2C2_SlaveSetReadIntHandler(i2c_receive_data);
I2C2_SlaveSetAddrIntHandler(i2c_receive_address);
```

In the MCC configuration for the MSSP, be sure to check "Interrupt Driven".

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how to configure a PIC as an I2C slave. But this could be due to your PIC not responding to **Write** commands.

By the way, this a very convoluted code for a I2C scan. You have more simple one in EasyMCP2221's examples repository. Like this:

```py
# Very simple I2C scan
import EasyMCP2221

# Connect to MCP2221
mcp = EasyMCP2221.Device()

# Optionally configure GP3 to show I2C bus activity.
mcp.set_pin_function(gp3 = "LED_I2C")

print("Searching...")

for addr in range(0, 0x80):
    try:
        mcp.I2C_read(addr)
        print("I2C slave found at address 0x%02X" % (addr))

    except EasyMCP2221.exceptions.NotAckError:
        pass
```

Can you try with this one, please? I uses **Read** instead of write.

**Edit**: Also, check your I2C bus clock. Try inserting this statement before the loop:

```py
mcp.I2C_speed(speed=100000)
```